# Populate text boxes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am retrieving a single row (using a method) from a table, I want to populate each column from this row into text boxes. How can this be done in VB.net.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i = 0 to Table.Rows.Count -1
    dim row as DataRow = Table.Rows(i)
    dim txt as new textbox
    txt.Text = row(i)
    panel1.controls.add(txt)
Next
```

where panel1 is a FlowLayoutPanel(it automatically positions the textboxes for you)

Answer (score 1):

If I read what you said correctly, you want a text box for each column in the datarow.  So you want something like this:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To row.ItemArray.Length - 1
        Dim txtBox As New TextBox
        txtBox.Text = row.Item(i).ToString
        Form1.Controls.add(txtBox)
    Next
```

Row being replaced with the method that returns your row, and whatever control you are adding the text box to in place of the Form1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several ways...but I think DataBinding may be the most generally accepted method. The problem with DataBinding is that you cannot bind to a DataRow. You must bind to the DataRow's Table.

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "ColumnName");
```

Check out more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) if you wish.